# Mysql subquery with "in" problem to associate parent table

Tags: sql, subquery

I try to create a query who select the contacts information (table `invoice_contacts`), and the adresses (table `invoice_adresses`) associate to the contact which is the most used in the (table `invoice_compta`)

For exemple I have two contact :

- Mike
- John

Mike have 2 adresses :

- Paris
- London

Mike have 1 invoice with Paris, and 5 invoice with London, so I want the adresse of London associate to Mike.

I have try this query with an subquery which count all adresses associate to the contact for an adresses (with `NB_ADRESSES`), and select only the biggest (with `order by NB_ADRESSES desc` and `limit 1`), it's seem wells but I have an error when I do `where ia2.ID_CONTACT = ic.ID_CONTACT` ic.ID_CONTACT is not found.. (and I need to associate the contact to the subquery).

```
select      ic.*,
            ia.*
from        invoice_contacts ic
left join   invoice_adresses ia on ia.ID_CONTACT = ic.ID_CONTACT
and         ia.ID_ADRESSE in    (
                                    select  ia3.ID_ADRESSE
                                    from    (
                                                select      ia2.ID_ADRESSE,
                                                            count(*) as NB_ADRESSES
                                                from        invoice_adresses ia2
                                                left join   invoice_comptas ico on ico.ID_ADRESSE_CONTACT = ia2.ID_ADRESSE
                                                where       ia2.ID_CONTACT = ic.ID_CONTACT
                                                group by    ia2.ID_ADRESSE
                                                order by    NB_ADRESSES desc
                                                limit       1
                                            ) as ia3
                                )
group by    ic.ID_CONTACT
order by    CONTACT_TITRE asc
```

I also have try with "exist" or "inner join" instead of "in" but I doesn't find good results, so the best way seems it to be with this query for me, but I don't found the solution.

I hope you will help me :)

Thanks

**UPDATE :**
So finally I have found an solution with this query :

```
select      ic.*,
            ia.*
from        invoice_contacts ic
left join   invoice_adresses ia on ia.ID_CONTACT = ic.ID_CONTACT
and         ia.ID_ADRESSE = (
                                select      ia3.ID_ADRESSE
                                from        (
                                                select      ia2.*,
                                                            count(*) as NB_ADRESSES
                                                from        invoice_adresses ia2
                                                left join   invoice_comptas ico on ico.ID_ADRESSE_CONTACT = ia2.ID_ADRESSE
                                                group by    ia2.ID_ADRESSE
                                            ) as ia3
                                where       ia3.ID_CONTACT = ic.ID_CONTACT
                                order by    NB_ADRESSES desc
                                limit   1
                            )
group by    ic.ID_CONTACT
order by    CONTACT_TITRE asc
```

Thanks

Comment: Mike has three addresses?  You have only specified two.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes thanks I have correct with two

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase the problem as finding the most common contact/address combination for a given invoice.

I find it hard to follow your query and your table naming.  But this is the idea:

```
select contact, address
from (select contact, address, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by contact order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from invoices
      group by contact, address
     ) ca
where seqnum = 1;
```

The subquery is counting the number of times a given address (or city if you prefer) occur for each contact.  The `row_number()` enumerates these, so the most common one has a value of "1".  The outer query then chooses the most common value.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I doesn't know the partition method but it seems not working with my version of mysql, but I understand what you mean with your query, finnaly I just found a solution for my problem (I will update my post)

Comment: @FlorianRichard . . . This answer is standard SQL, which is how your question is tagged.  You have not specified the database you are using.